# Here Android Sdk - onStopoverReached fired with wrong index

Tags: android, here-api

I've a list of waypoint of type `STOP_WAYPOINT` and `onStopoverReached` is fired with the wrong index (the `var1` parameter). The route has the following coordinates:

> latitude:42.896241 longitude:13.894039
>   latitude:42.897784 longitude:13.894991
>   latitude:42.89753 longitude:13.892602
>   latitude:42.896667 longitude:13.893728

It always recognize the first or the second, even if I reach the other ones.
The same function works flawlessly on the iOS SDK. Any clue?

```
private NavigationManager.NavigationManagerEventListener m_navigationManagerEventListener = new  NavigationManager.NavigationManagerEventListener() {        
        @Override
        public void onStopoverReached(int var1)
        {
            //var1 is the wrong index
        }
}

m_navigationManager.addNavigationManagerEventListener( new  WeakReference<NavigationManager.NavigationManagerEventListener>(m_navigationManagerEventListener));
```

Comment: Can you post some code snippet showing how you are 'firing' the `onStopoverReached` please.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport question updated.I've a simple listener added to the navigation manager. Using `NavigationManager.simulate` works as expected but when I use `NavigationManager.startNavigation` a lot of STOP_WAYPOINT are not detected.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport sorry, after further investigation I've discovered that the listener is fired correctly, but with the wrong index. I've updated my question.

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot reproduce the issue with wrong index. Did you manage to solve it? Or can you provide more details?

Comment: @Andrew I still having problems. As a workaround I'm iterating through all the STOP_WAYPOINT calculating the distance from the current position and using the closest.

Comment: We cannot reproduce it. Can you update one of our github samples and if reproducible, share with us?

Answer (score 0):

In general the index returned from the callback are in sync with the provided Route plan and the same should be used to get the stop over waypoint.

From Documentation: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/guidance/NavigationManager.NavigationManagerEventListener.html#onStopoverReached-int-

```
public void onStopoverReached(int index)
Callback indicating that a route stopover has been reached.
Note that in addition to this, NavigationManager.ManeuverEventListener.onManeuverEvent() callback will also be received. Furthermore, note that a RouteWaypoint of type RouteWaypoint.Type.VIA_WAYPOINT is not considered to be a route stopover.

Parameters:
index - The index of the stopover that was reached, starting from 0. Stopovers can be retrieved by index from the RoutePlan.
See Also:
RoutePlan.getWaypoint(int)
```